# react-dates component doesn't allow selection of dates prior to current date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dates

I am using airbnb's [DateRangePicker](http://airbnb.io/react-dates/). Its current behavior doesn't allow selection of dates prior to the present date. How do I change it to allow selection of past dates as start date? [here](https://github.com/majapw/react-dates-demo/blob/master/src/App.js) is the code being used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just so you know, this is fully configurable and you can specify a prop to determine if a given candidate date is valid for entry (by default, this function makes dates in the past invalid, I believe)

Just pass this prop to determine that every date is in range:

```
<DRP isOutsideRange={() => false} />
```

For a little more context, see [this issue](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/985#issuecomment-361033750) where I found the answer